# Isochrones in R closing roads based on spatial overlays

Tags: r, sf, service-area, network-analysis

I am interested in comparing isochrone maps based on different road closure scenarios. I have some polygon layers that I would use to "remove" closed roads (e.g. due to flooding). I am aware of some network analysis packages in R such as [OSRM](https://rdrr.io/cran/osrm/) or the [mapboxapi](https://walker-data.com/mapboxapi/), but there seems to be no clear way to edit the networks these packages pull from their APIs. Is there a viable way to generate traffic isochrones in R, but with the capacity to edit / exlcude roads from the network?

Any advice on workflow or alternative packages?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to build your own OSRM server (docker containers are available, its not too arduous if you know docker) then you'll to get the road data in OSM form and for your study area and load into your OSRM (again, this is all well described in the OSRM server docs).

Then to do a road closure, remove the road from the OSRM input data, rebuild the routing data, load into your OSRM server, and do your queries.

I'm not sure if you can directly update the data once its been converted into OSRM - if it was possible to update a road with something like updating one row of one database table with "maxspeed=0" to make a road closure, that might be a lot quicker. But I'm not sure what format or where (a PostGIS db?) the converted road data goes into.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have seen some comments about this, but my question then is how to connect my R code with my own OSRM server instead of the package's API. Do you know? Apologies if the question is trivial, im still wrapping my thoughts around all of it.

Comment: Re my previous question, it seems like ``options(osrm.server = "http://my_server/")`` does the job https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/09/building-a-local-osrm-instance/

Comment: And here is how to set a back end for OSRM on Windows https://gist.github.com/AlexandraKapp/e0eee2beacc93e765113aff43ec77789